# Is there any way to allow others to contribute to Discord bot repositories without them seeing the tokens?

Tags: discord

The title is pretty self-explanatory, but I can elaborate here.

I am the owner of a Discord server and I have multiple bots I made myself which I added to the server. The source code is stored in a local repository and a remote one in GitHub and I have the bots running in a heroku remote server. Some of my friends want to contribute to the bots and I am willing to let them contribute, except for one thing - bot tokens. It's not that I can't trust them, but I don't want to take any risks of the tokens getting in the wrong hands. While I can regenerate them with literally a click of a button, I would have to update the CSV file containing all the bot tokens (to run the bots themselves), which is easy at first, but could easily become a nuisance if too many people got their hands on the token. (This is kind of a rare scenario and may seem like paranoia, but please bear with me.)

If I wasn't running the bots on a remote server, I could easily just use `.gitignore` to prevent the tokens from being pushed to remote, but that is not the case. Is there any way for me to allow others to contribute to my repository without them seeing the tokens? Or, is there an alternative method that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: How about put the token from env variable instead? or using args to supply token when run the bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Heroku, you can define enivronement variables from the Settings tab:

1. Navigate to your app dashboard
2. Click on the Settings tab
3. Click Reveal Config Vars
4. Add your token in the value field and name it as you wish (TOKEN for example)

Then in your bot code, replace your token by `process.env.TOKEN` *where TOKEN is the name that you defined in Heroku*

Comment: This works, but I just used `os.environ['token']`